# Удаление класса и текста из textarea по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице имеются блоки с одинаковыми `id`, `class` и с `data-block`, в котором разное содержание. Блоки генерируются с помощью *PHP*.

Я реализовал (насколько хватило знаний) добавление информации с `data-block` в поле `<textarea>` по клику на блок и добавление класса `selected`, чтобы показать, что на блок уже кликнули.

```js
$('.bc').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
$('#block').each(function() {
    $('.bc').click(function() {
        if ($('textarea.textarea').append($(this).data('block') + '\n')) { }
    });
});
```

```css
#block {
    background-color: #77bee2;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px #3fa3d6 solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
.selected {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" class="bc" data-block="Текст при клике">Просто нажми меня...</div>
<div id="block" class="bc" data-block="Ку, ку">А вот и я...</div>
<div>
    <textarea wrap="hard" rows="5" cols="20" class="textarea"></textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Со следующим шагом у меня возникли проблемы. Дальше я хочу сделать, чтобы при повторном клике на уже отмеченный блок не добавлялась повторно информация с `data-block`, а наоборот - удалялся класс `selected` и удалялась запись этого блока с `<textarea>`. Но "ничего пока не получается".

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mb1bh10a)

Comment: Строка `$('#block').each(function() {` бесполезна. Для чего она присутствует в коде? Кстати, создание нескольких элементов с одинаковым ID считается дурным тоном, и не просто так.

Comment: Без `.each` не работает клик более чем на один блок.

Comment: `$('.bc').click` добавляет обработчик события `click` всем элементам с классом `bc`. А `$('#block').each(function() {` делает ровно одну итерацию (если, конечно, элемент с ID `block` присутствует на странице. Если его нет - тогда ноль итераций).

Comment: @excellproj, на всякий случай отмечу, что согласно спецификации HTML значения аттрибута `id` должны быть **уникальными**.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, согласен. Перепишу. Спасибо за ценное замечание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать проверку на наличие класса `selected` у элемента, по которому кликнули, а дальше, в зависимости от логики приложения, производить какие-то действия с элементом. Например так:

```
var $tx = $('textarea.textarea');
$('.bc').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
        str = $el.data('block') + '\n';

    if ($el.hasClass('selected')) {
        // Блок УЖЕ имеет класс "selected"
        $el.removeClass('selected');
        $tx.val($tx.val().replace(str, ''));
    } else {
        // Блок ЕЩЕ НЕ имеет класс "selected"
        $el.addClass('selected');
        $tx.val($tx.val() + str);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Regent, так суть вопроса не только в переключении  классов, но и в выполнении других действий. Если бы все сводилось к переключению классов, то да, `toggleClass` было бы оптимальным решением

Comment: @Regent, добавил работу с `<textarea>`

Comment: Хотел, было, опять заикнуться про `.append()` вместо `.val()`, но `.val()` действительно более правильный подход.

Answer (score 0):

Немного поправил ваш код. Теперь он делает, что вы хотите:

```
$('.bc').click(function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
       $('textarea.textarea').val($('textarea.textarea').val() .replace($(this).data('block') + '\n',''));
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $('textarea.textarea').val($('textarea.textarea').val() + $(this).data('block') + '\n');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hsdj4nx/

Что этот код делает:

`$(this).hasClass('selected');` Проверяет, если ли у элемента уже класс `selected`, т.е. нажимали мы на него или еще нет.

Если нет то(т.е. еще не нажимали):

`$('textarea.textarea').val($('textarea.textarea').val() + $(this).data('block') + '\n');` Добавляем в `textarea` текст из дата атрибута `block`. Вы это уже делали

`$(this).addClass('selected');` Добавляем класс `selected`. Что бы изменить UI, и потом понимать что мы уже нажимали на этот элемента.

Если да то(т.е. уже нажимание):

`$('textarea.textarea').val($('textarea.textarea').val() .replace($(this).data('block') + '\n',''));` Удаляем первое включение текста.

`$(this).removeClass('selected');` Удаляем класс `selected`. Что бы изменить UI, и потом понимать что мы еще не нажимали на этот элемента.

Comment: Вызывать `$(this)` в каждом обработчике события трижды - это расточительно. К тому же, я не совсем понимаю, чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от моего ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev тем что я ответил на вопрос раньше, что вы там наредактировали я не проверял. Если считаете что ответ не правильно или вредный, думаю вы знаете как выразить это.

Comment: @Vartlok, вы правы. Минус за расточительное использование `$(...)`

Comment: @Vartlok спасибо за Ваш ответ и описание,